# Insert new rows and also increment date inside cell

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I have a vba code which will duplicate rows x number of times depending on the value specific cell.

It works perfectly but I need your help to improve it further. In one of my cells, I have date values and whenever I insert a row I want it to increment +1 day.

Here's my current code:

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim VInSertNum As Variant
xRow = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
    VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "E")
    If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
       Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "E")).Copy
       Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "E")).Select
       Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
       xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
    End If
    xRow = xRow + 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Sample data

```
  Name           Date      Number of Duplicates
 Michael      05/06/2018              2
 Jane         07/06/2018              2
```

Desired Output:

```
 Name           Date       Number of Duplicates
Michael      05/06/2018              2
Michael      05/07/2018              2
Jane         07/06/2018              2
Jane         07/07/2018              2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add `Cells(xRow, 2).Value = Cells(xRow, 2).Value + 1` before the `End If`.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim VInSertNum As Variant
xRow = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
    VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "E")
    If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
       Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "E")).Copy
       Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "E")).Select
       Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
       xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
       Cells(xRow, 2).Value = Cells(xRow, 2).Value + 1
    End If
    xRow = xRow + 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very. This is very helpful! :)